# Hue Bulbs cause other fixture to flicker

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

So I have some hue GU10 bulbs in a fixture. The fixture is a dimming fixture so the bulbs do buzz a tiny bit so I shut of the fixture at night. However when the bulbs are turned on, other bulbs in a different fixture start to repeatedly pulse on and off.

I have no Idea what is causing the flickering apart from the hue lights. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "dimming fixture"?  If you replaced the Hue bulbs with incandescent, would you be able to dim them?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yes, If I put incandescent bulbs into this fixture the lights will be able to dim.